# How would I configure a geoserver store using jTDS?

Tags: geoserver, jetty

I'm trying to create a GeoServer docker container, which accesses a SQL Server database, and would prefer to use the jTDS driver over the Microsoft one--besides the fact that it's supposed to be faster, installing the Microsoft driver into a docker container is a pain (the URL keeps changing).

My GeoServer install includes the `sqlserver` plugin, and so consequently, among `Stores` I see options for `Microsoft SQL Server (JNDI)` and `Microsoft SQL Server (JTDS Driver) (JNDI)`.

When I add `libtds-java` to my (ubuntu-based) docker, and copy the `jtds.jar` file to my `$GEOSERVER_HOME/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/` directory, then I get a `Microsoft SQL Server (JTDS Driver)` option, so that would appear to have found the appropriate driver.

But any attempt to create a Store results in the error `Error creating data store, check the parameters. Error message: Could not acquire data access`. I see this error mentioned for many reasons on the mailing list, and it appears usually to be a permissions problem on the data directory, but the docker is running as user `www-data`, everything in the data directory is owned by `www-data`, and if I exec `bash` in the docker I can manually create files in the data directory. Or I can run the docker as root, and still see the same error.

What's more, if I install the Microsoft driver, I can create stores using it.

Yet, I've seen mention that the jTDS driver works, so what do I need to do to configure it?

Tomcat solutions are acceptable. I'm not totally tied to the Jetty implementation. I suspect, in the end, adding the GeoServer war to a standard Tomcat docker would be simpler, anyway (though I'm not sure about the plugins).

And yeah, the real solution would be to use PostGIS. Why we use SQLServer is beyond me.

Comment: you need to install the whole plugin not just the jtds jar, next check the log file for a fuller error message.

Comment: also the latest plugin is expecting version 1.3.1 of the jtds  jar

Comment: @iant I _have_ installed the whole plugin. The sqlserver plugin works fine. But the _driver_ is only the `jtds.jar` file (just as the Microsoft driver is only the `sqljdbc42.jar`). As for the fuller message, _that's it_! You'd think after 6 years or more of seeing this, someone would have fixed GeoServer to not swallow the original error (which clearly is a whole bunch of different errors).  However, the most likely problem would be the 1.3.1 version.  Ubuntu/Debian, are, as usual, well behind upstream versions. I'll get it from sourceforge and see if that helps.

Comment: did you turn logging up to developer level?

Comment: I turned logging up to Verbose, which I understood to be the most detailed.

Comment: @iant Perfect! After all my messing about, changing from the jTDS driver in Ubuntu (1.2.5) to the current version in Sourceforge solves the problem. Thanks.